# gmail SMTP using System::Net::Mail::SmtpClient partial chain error

Tags: ssl-certificate, .net-2.0

I'm using `System::Net::Mail::SmtpClient` in `.net-2.0` to send emails via gmail SMTP with SSL/TLS, as of last Friday, this has started sporadically failing. I don't get these issues with my development machine, only the Windows XP embedded system our product uses.

I've narrowed the issue down, thanks to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633677(v=exchg.80).aspx), to a [PartialChain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chainstatusflags(v=vs.110).aspx) error. Alot of the certificates on this embedded system are out of date. The embedded system has the "Add/Remove Windows Components" disabled, so I'm unable to set Windows to update the certificates. So I've tried updating the certificates directly with the output of openSSL using `openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465 -showcerts`, there's two certificates in there and I've copied and pasted them into text files, renamed the files .crt, and I've imported them using the Windows MMC control following the guide [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb950259(v=bts.10).aspx). I've tried importing them as `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` and `Third-Party Root Certification Authorities` for both the `Local Computer` and `Certificates - Current User`. I've also tried downloading the Root certificates for Geotrust, which was referred to by the answer in [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/498588/smtp-gmail-com-from-bash-gives-error-in-certificate-peers-certificate-issuer) stackoverflow page, when dealing with certificate issues with gmail SMTP, but it hasn't resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that all I needed was the GeoSign root certificates, all 3 copies, which has cross-signed the Google certificate authority root certificate. And the Google certificate chain as outputted from OpenSSL.